# What is the last Unix time?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, unix-timestamp

What is the last Unix time in decimal? I'm going to set it as the expiration date of cookies (using PHP). Is it possible to cause problem?

Comment: Wikipedia's your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem (Google would be, too)

Comment: By the way, cookies don't use the Unix time for timestamps but RFC 2822.

Comment: @Boldewyn yeah, but PHP's `setcookie()` does, stupidly imposing a totally unnecessary limitation. On the other hand, this shouldn't really be that often needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2147483647

Answer (score 7):

Sunday, December 4, 292,277,026,596 AD (on 64-bit systems)

Comment: +1 for the answer that will be relevant in 2038. (Of course some software will break long before then eg. Poorly implemented mortgage calculators)

Comment: I can see us having the same calendar in 2038, I'm *not* so sure we'll have the same one in 200 trillion years into the future, especially since the only planet it makes sense on would have been swallowed by its sun trillions of years before-hand :-)

Answer (score 6):

For a 32-bit `time_t` value, you will overflow in mid to late January 2038. Specifically about 3:14 AM UTC on January 19 (actually somewhere between 3:14 and 3:15 but that should be close enough for you).

The maximum value is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or 2,147,483,647.